# Folland Real Analysis Exercise 5.15 - A unique linear tranformation $S$ such that $T = S \circ \pi$ where $\pi$ is the projection onto $X/N(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

Consider the following problem, Exercise 15 of chapter 5 of Folland's *Real Analysis*, 2nd edition:

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are normed vector spaces and $T \in L(X, Y)$. Let $N(T) = \{x \in X \ : \ Tx = 0\}$.
>
> a. Show that $N(T)$ is a closed subspace.
>
> b. Show that there exists a unique $S \in L(X/N(T), Y)$ such that $T = S \circ \pi$ where $\pi: X \to X/N(T)$ is the canonical projection, and that $||S|| = ||T||$.

Part a. is clear. My question regards item b.. I tried defining $S(x + N(T)) = T(x)$. Is it really that trivial? I think I am missing something. Regarding the equality of norms, I was able to show that $||S|| \geq ||T||$:
$$
\sup_{||x + N(T)|| \leq 1} |S(x + N(T)| = \sup_{||x + N(T)|| \leq 1} |T(x)| = \sup_{\inf_{y \in N(T)} ||x - y|| \leq 1} |T(x)| \geq||T||,
$$
but I am stuck with the other inequality.

Any help will be the most appreciated.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am stuck with the other inequality.*

Given $t\in N(T)$ and $x\in X$, we have
$$\|S(\pi(x))\|=\|T(x)\|=\|T(x+t)\|\leq \|T\|\|x+t\|$$
and thus
$$\|S(\pi(x))\|\leq \inf_{t\in N(T)} \|T\|\|x+t\|=\|T\|\|\pi(x)\|,\quad\forall\ x\in X.$$
Therefore,
$$\|S\|=\sup_{\substack{x\in X\\ x\neq 0}}\frac{S(\pi(x))}{\|\pi(x)\|}\leq \|T\|$$

*Edit in response to the comment.*

**Existence.** Define $S:X/N(T)\to X$ by $S(\pi(x))=T(x)$. Show that $S$ is well-defined. It is clear that $T=S\circ \pi$.

**Uniqueness.** Suppose that $\tilde{S}:X/N(T)\to X$ satisfies $T=\tilde{S}\circ \pi$. Then
$$\tilde{S}(z)=\tilde{S}(\pi(x))=T(x)=S(\pi(x))=S(z),\quad\forall \ z=\pi(x)\in X/N(T)$$
and thus $\tilde{S}=S$.

Comment: Thank you very much. In what regards the existence and uniqueness of a map $S$, what can we say?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

Pick a sequence $y_n\in N(T)$ such that $\|x+y_n\|\to\|x+N(T)\|$. Then $$\|S(x+N(T))\|=\|Tx\|=\|T(x+y_n)\|\leq\|T\|\|x+y_n\|\to\|T\|\|x+N(T)\|$$ So $\|S\|\le\|T\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much. What about the existence and uniqueness of a map $S$?

Comment: For existence, all you need more is to show that it is well-defined: if $x+N(T)=y+N(T)$ then $Tx=Ty$. Uniqueness is obvious from $T=S\circ\pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Show fist that $S(\pi(x))=Tx$ is well defined. Uniqueness will follow from there to by assuming there is another such R and checking they coincide.